# How can I show variable width slides without cutting them with slick?

Tags: jquery, carousel, slick.js

I'm using [Slick carousel](https://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/) to make a carousel for my website. The last slide is cut, so I would like to make it disappear if it isn't shown full, as you can see in this image:

[image]

How can I do that?

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="carousel">
    <!-- here is a loop -->
    <div>
      <img src=":img:full:img:">
    </div>
    <!-- end loop -->
  </div>
</div>
```

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.carousel').slick({
    slidesToScroll: 1,
    autoplaySpeed: 3000,
    variableWidth: true,
    infinite: true,
  });
});
```

Comment: increase spacing between each slide, so that the last slide will come as a full slide upon scrolling

Comment: I've tried but there are more slides with different width sizes

Comment: you can fix widths of each slide, it will fix your problem

Comment: I could but if I do that I have  to fix every width of each slide that I add to the carousel. There couldn't be another way?

Answer (score 0):

The parameter `variableWidth` it self means that you are using the slides with the auto width, so it's depend upon your images/logos's width. either you should have same width logo's or false the `variableWidth` option.

Adjusting with the css is not a good option. :)